# R: How to use stringr to extract the substring as the output to mutate a column of strings that begins with a string pattern and end with a number?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I'm creating a small example to be put into mutate(). Not sure why this doesn't work.

```
> str_extract("rs1234-<b>C</b>","^rs*\\d$")
[1] NA
```

I'd be great if you can point to my misunderstanding of the language instead of merely providing a solution. I expect to get "rs1234".

Comment: What do you expect to get? `str_extract("rs1234-<b>C</b>", "^rs\\d+")`?

Comment: I expect to get "rs1234"

Comment: It returns NA because your `\\d$` doesn't match ie.. there is no digit at the end of the string where `$` stands for the end of string

Comment: But if I just want the substring in between "rs" and the last number. What should I do?

Comment: In base R using capture groups - `sub('(^rs\\d+).*', '\\1', "rs1234-<b>C</b>")`

Answer (score 2):

The `^rs*\d$` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `rs*` - `r` and zero or more occurrences of `s` char
- `\d` - a digit
- `$` - end of string.

So, your pattern matches strings like `rsssss1`, `r3`, etc.

You need

```r
str_extract("rs1234-<b>C</b>", "^rs\\d+")
```

where `^rs\d+` matches `rs` at the start of string and then one or more digits. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KjWIxk/1).

> But if I just want the substring in between "rs" and the last number. What should I do?

You would use `rs.*\d`:

```r
str_extract("rs1234-<b>C</b>", "rs.*\\d")
```

where `rs.*\d` matches `rs`, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a digit.

NOTE: If you need to match line endings, too, you need to prepend the last pattern with `(?s)` inline DOTALL modifier.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KjWIxk/2).

Comment: Thanks! So there must be a misunderstanding of me about the execution order. How should I know which operations takes higher priority? I thought that what I did would give me a string that start with "rs" and end with a digit because I used start with "^" and end with "$" with their respective arguments. Why didn't this give me the result? What did I get wrong? Any good resource to learn the language rules thoroughly?

Comment: What's the difference between "*" and "."? I thought "*" means basically anything?

Comment: @monotonic Then you wanted `^rs.*\d$` / `(?s)^rs.*\d$`.